# Is it possible to define an extension method on a generic type and return another generic type without defining two generic types in <>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this TInput input) {
```

and use:

```
item.ConvertType<NewObject>()
```

or do I have to do this:

```
public static TResult ConvertType<TInput, TResult>(this TInput input) {
```

and use:

```
item.ConvertType<OriginalObject, NewObject>()
```

It seems so redundant to have to specify the type the extension method is called on, am I missing something?

Comment: You have to specify them on the method signature, but on the method call the compiler *might* be able to infer them from the provided arguments and the type you are trying to return it into.

Comment: if you do `NewObject ob = item.ConvertType()` compiler will now it's conversion between `OriginalObject` and `NewObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, basically. There are a few tricks you can do, but only if it important enough.

You can do something like:

```
var dest = item.Convert().To<Something>();
```

via something like:

```
static ConversionStub<TInput> Convert<TInput>(this TInput input) {
    return new ConversionStub<TInput>(input); }
```

where:

```
struct ConversionStub<T> {
    private readonly T input;
    public ConversionStub(T input) { this.input = input; }
    public TResult To<TResult>() {
        /* your code here */
    }
}
```

You can also do some things with `dynamic` by hooking the operator path, but that would cause boxing for value-types; but if your `Convert` method returned `dynamic`, where the `dynamic` in question is your own provider, that would work.

But basically:

```
class ConversionStub<T> : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly T input;
    public ConversionStub(T input){
        this.input = input;
    }
    public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if(/* you can do it*/ )
        {
            result = // your code here
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

with:

```
static dynamic Convert<TInput>(this TInput input) {
    return new ConversionStub<TInput>(input); }
```

Then:

```
SomeType dest = item.Convert();
```

should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the alternate solution.